# React : Sort Method is not working for all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, loopbackjs

I am working on ReactJS project . Actually I am using `semantic UI React Sort` for sorting of data but problem is that it can just sort data on current page. I mean I am using pagination in my project , Let suppose if user on page 2 if user click on table header to sort in `asc` or `desc` it can sort data just for page 2. I want if user click on table header so I want to sorting for all not just for current page . I am beginner to ReactJS , Could someone please help me how to solve this problem . Thanks

Sorry , If I made some mistake in English Grammer . I am not native speaker

**Code**

```
    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Is this a new account again ? This is the third time I see this question

Comment: Yes , Actually my old account was suspended. I need to solve this problem urgently . Could you please help me ?

Comment: You have to sort the whole set of your data, not the part you are showing. I think it may be better to do it server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [way(client side or server side) to go for pagination /sortable columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962557/wayclient-side-or-server-side-to-go-for-pagination-sortable-columns)

Comment: You can find many examples here on SO

Comment: Actually , I am using Loopback API and Loopback provide filter for `asc` and `desc` but problem is that I am beginner and don't have knowledge to create logic for this

Comment: I understand, but people here are not going to do it for you, you'll have to learn by yourself. Maybe you should start whitout pagination ? You already did a good job fetching the api, keep going :)

Comment: Actually , Everything is working fine but I am using `semantic UI React` sort Method `handleSort = clickedColumn => ()` . It let me sort only existing page but for all data which are stored in `data` state